# Error al tratar usar conexion con mysql en Servidor apache Tomcat en la Nube(hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat

Tengo un error al tratar de realizar la ejecucion de mi aplicativo web en un servidor web llamado facilcloud (jelastic), mi proyecto esta trabajando con mysql hibernate, mongodb,java 1.6, spring mvc, bootstrap, maven entre otras herramientas.

El problema que tengo es cuando ejecuto la aplicacion ya desplegada en el servidor en la nube. Desde el index trato de crear un usuario de la app y este se queda pegado debido a que en el log de apache tomcat hay error con el siguiente mensaje, el cual segun he consultado hace referencia a la versión del jdk, pero eh intentado crear un servidor con la misma version de jdk y cambiar la versión de jdk de mi proyecto por medio de eclipse y este error continua, gracias por la colaboración.

Adjunto imágenes de la configuración de mi ambiente local con las versiones de jdk que uso para compilar y la versión de jdk del proyecto en sí.

> INFO :
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -
>   Pre-instantiating singletons in
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@527a9c0f:
>   defining beans
>   [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,mongoConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,mongoDbFactory,mongoTemplate];
>   root of factory hierarchy
>   test--testt--1234567378--drizzleweb@icloud.com--2002-03-19--1234567890--0
>   Initial SessionFactory creation
>   failed.java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>   (unable to load class org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration)

---

Configuración de la applicación en el ambiente local de desarrollo:

[image: Configuración de la applicación en el ambiente local de desarrollo]

Versión de JDK con el que se compila y ejecuta localmente, además de la versión del Servidor Web Local:

[image: Versión de JDK con el que se compila y ejecuta localmente, además de la versión del Servidor Web Local]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo con la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError.html):

> Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine attempts to read a class file and
>   determines that the major and minor version numbers in the file are
>   not supported.

En español:

> Es lanzada cuando la JVM intenta leer un archivo `.class` y determina
>   que la versión menor y mayor en el archivo no son soportadas.

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable 
to load class org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration)
```

Habla de un error en la versión `52.0`(java 8), que según [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file):

1. Java SE 9 = 53
2. Java SE 8 = 52
3. Java SE 7 = 51
4. Java SE 6.0 = 50
5. Java SE 5.0 = 49
6. JDK 1.4 = 48
7. JDK 1.3 = 47
8. JDK 1.2 = 46
9. JDK 1.1 = 45

Eso quiere decir que en Jelastic/Facilcloud está utilizando java `1.8` y según sus imágenes, la configuración local es de java `1.6`

Asegúrese de tener las versiones acordes, ésto debería solucionar éste error.